# Sentence improvement too redundant

Tags: phrase-requests, british-english, sentence, writing-advice

Can this be improved?

> The last tale of success on a constructed new programming language is
> one at the famous X, LLC.

or,

> The last tale of success **of** a constructed new programming language is
> one at the famous X, LLC.

I see some redundancy, but, cannot come up with proper improvement.

NOT sure which tag to select, I thought, that "sentence improvement" would exist, or something similar. I am new here.

**EDIT:** `on a constructed new programming language is one at` that line seems strange every time I read it.

**EDIT1:** Googling, *"The last tale of success"* gives only one result, notably this https://www.thedailystar.net/op-ed/economics/the-hurt-the-average-4912, which includes the following sentence:

> **The last tale of success** was from an Indian, which was perhaps the
> biggest of them all, who had multi-capabilities, manufactured all
> types of garments and shared with us that boards ought to only look at
> capex (capital expenditures) and audits while the core job had to be
> intelligently delegated.

---

I been writing tales about various successes in programming languages. Then, I want to add a last and final tale concerning the success of a language created at X,LLC. One can add keyword, e.g., a form of transition word such as, `lastly` or `finally` but, I want to keep a flow without redundancy and make it easy for the reader to keep reading.

**EDIT:** Given the success of the other stories I wrote about previously, it seems natural to start the next sentence with: **The last tale of success**.

---

**A potential sentence improvement:**

> The last tale of success was from the famous X, LLC. that constructed
> new programming language to solve Y.

Comment: What is the sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: @alphabet, please see my **EDIT(s)**

Comment: Are you saying that the *language's construction* was a success, or that the *language that was constructed* was a success?

Comment: Latter would be more correct here. `the language that was constructed was a success` by constructing it, they earned their success. However, this is implied by the continues expansion about it and what they did exactly. But, for now, this sentence alone is intended for starting that paragraph.

Comment: @alphabet, I have sentences before this one, this is the last paragraph as a continuation to the ones before. Meaning, I written paragraphs on the success stories of other constructed programming languages that addressed limitations and problems not solve by e.g., language X, Y, or Z etc. Hopefully you get the idea of what I am intending here.

Comment: @alphabet, is the sentence in its current written form, acceptable? Grammatically, technically speaking.

Comment: A tale of success is usually known as a **success story**. *Your* last tale is not *the* last tale, only "My last success story" or "One last success story" and no more.

Comment: @YosefBaskin No, but it may be the last one discussed in that piece of writing. And the *my* not be consistent with the style of the prose.  *Success story* definitely seems like a suggestion.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him, YES, the last one discussed. EXACTLY.

Comment: I don't like ***on*** or ***of*** in your example text (I'd probably use ***about*** myself). But the question looks like proofreading to me anyway.

Comment: Does the following sentence corresponds to the sense you are looking for ? "*The last tale tells the success story of the construction of x,LLc, an innovative programming language*. If so, we can try to improve it.